# CSV point coordinates not showing on QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, coordinates, csv

I'm using QGIS 3.26.3-1. I have data on Coordinates of Health Facilities in in a subcounty. I have the layer of the sub-county already loaded onto QGIS then followed by the layer on health facilities. However, the points do not appear on the QGIS Map. I have attempted to troubleshoot using previous answers to similar questions but still no points are showing.

[image: The health facilities with Coordinates]
[image: Adding Text Delimited Layer]
[image: No Points]

Comment: Uncheck the "DMS coordinates" checkbox and everything should be fine.

Comment: Thank You so Much Erik It Worked!